# How to create a table in word document with data from gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, word-automation

while exporting data from gridview to word file a table should be created in word ,

Table may contain many cells ,

In each cell i need to store one record exporting from gridview

```
I have exported the data from gridview to word, 


like this  


1       rasdf           sdf     
2       sdf         jlkj        
3       dfdf            dfdf        
4       dsaf            sdfdsfds        
5       king            mumbai  



but i need the output in table format in which Each record should be in one cell,  second cell contains another records
![OUTput view is attached with this link][1]
```

[image]

**This is code i have written**

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                      //  Table table = new table();
            sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.doc)|*.doc";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
              ExportToWord(); 
                } 
        }
private void ExportToWord()
        {
string strForPrint = "";

            //writing bill fields
           // strForPrint += "Bill No : " + txtBillNo.Text + "\t";
            //strForPrint += "Date : " + dtpDate.Text + "\r\n\r\n";
            //strForPrint += "Customer Name : " + txtCustomer.Text + "\r\n\r\n";
            //strForPrint += "Remarks : " + txtRemarks.Text + "\r\n\r\n\r\n";
            strForPrint += "-----Bill Detail-----" + "\r\n\r\n\r\n";


                // writing datagridview column titles:

               string strHeaderTitle = "";

                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                   strHeaderTitle = strHeaderTitle.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t\t";
                }

                //strForPrint += strHeaderTitle + "\r\n";

                // writing datagridview data.

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    string strLineData = "";

                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    {
                          strLineData = strLineData.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                            if (j == 1)
                            {
                                strLineData = strLineData + "\t\t\t";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strLineData = strLineData + "\t\t";
                            }
                        }


                        strForPrint += strLineData + "\r\n";


                }


            Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);


            byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(strForPrint);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create);

            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

          bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write data into file
          MessageBox.Show("File Created.....");

            bw.Flush();

            bw.Close();

            fs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Beware, this line is wrong: "sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.doc)|*.doc";" Excel extension is xsl or xlsx, not doc

Comment: Ya it was word document "sfd.Filter = "word document (.doc)|.doc";"

Answer (score 0):

This is a really ugly way of creating a Words documents.. Even if it could work, you wont have control of the formatting as you seems to need. I highly recommend to use some library to create real word documents, like WordDocumentGenerator or similar.

http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com/

Another approach could be to use an XSL template to transform xml data obtained from database.

http://securityroots.com/dradispro/support/guides/reports_xslt.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872374(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I like [DocX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra), available via NuGet and very easy to use.